# Create SageMaker Instance for multiple users via terraform

Tags: terraform, aws-cli, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-sagemaker

I have below module for creating SageMaker Instances from terraform.
Below is my sagemaker module:-

```
resource "aws_sagemaker_notebook_instance" "sagemaker" {
count                 = length(var.users)
name                  = "${var.notebook_prefix}-${var.users[count.index]}-notebook"
role_arn              = length(var.role_arn) > 0 ? element(var.role_arn, count.index) : ""
instance_type         = var.instance_type
direct_internet_access = "Disabled"
subnet_id             = var.subnet_id
security_groups       = var.security_groups
lifecycle_config_name = "lifecycle-${var.users[count.index]}"
}
```

Below is my main.tf file :-

```
module "sagemaker-notebook" {
source          = "above module"
notebook_prefix = "prod"
resource_prefix = "abc"
role_arn        =  <arn>
instance_type   = "ml.m5.2xlarge"
users           = values(var.user)
security_groups = [<id>]
subnet_id       = "<subnet_id>"
on_start        = base64encode(data.template_file.init.rendered)
on_create       = base64encode(data.template_file.create.rendered)
}
```

Below is my variables.tf

```
variable "user" {
type = "map"
default = {
"1"   = "abc"
"2"   = "def"
"3"   = "xyz"
"4"   = "pqr"
}
}
```

The issue I am facing is as below :-
Whenever I remove/add any user from above variable it ask me to destroy all the resources and recreate all of them as it tries to replace each other in their place like if I remove "pqr" from the list then it  replace each of them.
Can we ignore this kind of behavior ?

Comment: You should use a `for_each` to loop over the resources instead to avoid this reordering removing other, unrelated resources.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, when I am using the for_each under module I am getting below error :-

`Error: Reserved argument name in module block`

  `on main.tf line 79, in module "sagemaker-ds-notebook":`
  `79:   for_each = var.user_ds`

`The name "for_each" is reserved for use in a future version of Terraform.`
`Terraform v0.12.28`